# XML - XPath --- Finding all same level nodes as the one containing a certain text

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I know the title might be a bit hard to understand but I'll do my best to explain what I need in here. Here I'll first give you my XML code.

```
<stamoudste soort="man">
  <naam>Geert</naam>
  <kind soort="zoon">
    <naam>Kurt</naam>
  </kind>
  <kind soort="dochter">
    <naam>An</naam>
    <kind soort="zoon">
      <naam>Michael</naam>
      <kind soort=" zoon">
        <naam>Bert</naam>
      </kind>
    </kind>
  </kind>
  <kind soort=" dochter ">
    <naam>Nele</naam>
    <kind soort=" dochter ">
      <naam>Paul ine</naam>
    </kind>
  </kind>
</stamoudste>
```

So as you can see there's a 'Kind' with the name 'An', now what I need to do is find her generation mates. So if in select.php - An - is selected, my - selected.php - should give me: 
An has a few generation members with names : Nele, An, Kurt.

Nele and Kurt are on the same level as 'An' and those are the ones I need to find with XPath but I have no clue how. I can find nodes containing the text 'An' but I need to find all the ones on the same level as the one containing 'An'.

If you could help me out I'd be very happy since I need this for an exam tomorow.

Edit:

I've been trying to use this code to read it, but it will always give me back the same names : An, Kurt, Nele. For the select of An, Kurt and Nele thats fine, but for the selection of Michael it should give back Pauline so I don't get it.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('familie.xml');
//$xPath = $xml->xpath("//naam[count(ancestor::*)=count(//naam[text()='An']/ancestor::*)]");
$xPath = $xml->xpath("//naam[.='".$_GET['naam']."']/ancestor::*");
//$xPath = $xml->xpath("//sibling::naam[.='An']/naam::*");

echo $_GET['naam']." heeft als generatie genoten: ";

foreach($xPath[0]->kind as $kind){
    $kindNaam = $kind->naam;
        echo $kindNaam." ";
}
?>
```

Comment: I get `Michele` and `Paul ine` when running the xpath I've provided in [videlibri](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi). Have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this could be simplified but I would do it this way:

```
//naam[count(ancestor::*)=count(//naam[text()='An']/ancestor::*)]
```

Basically, you get the depth level of `An` with:

```
count(//naam[text()='An']/ancestor::*)
```

And then you get all `naam` nodes that have the same depth level as the one returned above.

Comment: Uhm if you could show me some code in order how to echo these out too would be handfull so I could check it. Ty

Comment: You can check it [here](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi). Just make sure you select XPath in the textarea in the right and copy your XML in the textarea in the left

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `//kind[namm[.='An']]/naam/text()` - literally, the set of texts of `naam` elements contained within a `kind` element that contains a `naam` element with the text value "An".

Alternatively, you could use the `sibling` axis: `//sibling::naam[.='An']/naam/text()` - the set of texts of `naam` elements that are siblings of a `naam` element with the text value "An".

Answer (score 0):

Select all kind elements with naam "An":

`//kind[naam="An"]`

Here could be more then a single person named "An", so the next expression need to be done for each node.

Select the naam elements of the preceding siblings:

`preceding-sibling::kind/naam`

And the following siblings, too:

`preceding-sibling::kind/naam|following-sibling::kind/naam`

Full example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
  <stamoudste soort="man">
  <naam>Geert</naam>
  <kind soort="zoon">
    <naam>Kurt</naam>
  </kind>
  <kind soort="dochter">
    <naam>An</naam>
    <kind soort="zoon">
      <naam>Michael</naam>
      <kind soort=" zoon">
        <naam>Bert</naam>
      </kind>
    </kind>
  </kind>
  <kind soort=" dochter ">
    <naam>Nele</naam>
    <kind soort=" dochter ">
      <naam>Paul ine</naam>
    </kind>
  </kind>
</stamoudste>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->evaluate(
  '//kind[naam = "An"]'
);
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $siblingNodes = $xpath->evaluate(
    'preceding-sibling::kind/naam|following-sibling::kind/naam', $node
  );
  $siblings = array();
  foreach ($siblingNodes as $siblingNode) {
    $siblings[] = $siblingNode->nodeValue;
  }
  var_dump(
    array(
      'name' => $xpath->evaluate(
        'string(naam)', $node
      ),
      'siblings' => $siblings
    )
  );
}
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(2) "An"
  ["siblings"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Kurt"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Nele"
  }
}
```